# Bulkhead (Forward and Rear) positions in civil aircraft

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-structures

I am looking for general positions of forward and rear bulkheads in the civil aviation aircraft. Like, at what percentage of fuselage length from fuselage nose or any other reference point?

Any reference reading material also would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Bulkheads are used to enclose the pressurized part of the airframe, so they are just as far apart as that portion of the fuselage.

In a jetliner the forward bulkhead is normally just behind the weather radar while the backward bulkhead is just before the tailcone.

On this A330 cutaway ([source](https://img146.imageshack.us/img146/4351/eadsa330mrtttanker2007b.jpg)), they are the number 5 and 158 respectively:

[image: A330 cutaway]

Obviously in an airplane like the B-52 only the cabin needs to be pressurised and the bulkheads are positioned accordingly, 4 and 42 in this cutaway ([source](https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/493496071652815088/)):

[image: B-52 cutaway]

Comment: Just a clarification:  While bulkheads can be used for separation of pressurized sections of the fuselage from unpressurized sections, this kind of structural member is not exclusively used for that purpose.

Comment: @CarloFelicione: yes right, I've assumed the OP meant "pressure" buckheads ("*forward and rear*" in the title of the question). Thanks for the corrections 

Answer (score 0):

On each aircraft, locations are identified by station or frame numbers to facilitate manufacturing and maintenance tasks. For the fuselage these locations can correspond to circular frames used to reinforce the outer skin. The ends of the pressurized cabin correspond to two particular locations e.g. STA 178/STA 1016 for a Boeing 737 NG and FR1/FR77 for Airbus A320.

There are diagrams online showing the stations number, e.g. for a B737-800:

[image]

([Source](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/271942-zibo-b737-800-modified-in-x-plane-12/&page=138))

A quick online search will easily provide other diagrams for other aircraft. In spite actual lengths are not shown, it is possible to find the ratio you are searching for.

However aircraft families include models of different cabin lengths, to accommodate different customers needs. For example in the [A320 family](https://www.modernairliners.com/airbus-a320), the A318 (107 seats) is 31.4 m long while the A321 (180 seats) is 44.5 m long. As the the pressure vessel ends have fixed places (aft of radar antenna and forward of tail cone), the ratio pressure vessel / aircraft length will vary.